# How to get the parent value of <LI>

Tags: jquery, html

Fore example I have a list like this:

```
<ul id='left_faq_tips_navi'>
  <li>Test
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Test 2
     <ul>
       <li>C</li>
       <li>D</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the TEST 2 value when I click on "C".

```
var ul = $('#left_faq_tips_navi').find('ul').attr('id')
```

This result give me undefined answer.

Comment: Folks value of TEST 2 means ?? what exactly do you want ??

Comment: Is this useful: var ul = $("#left_faq_tips_navi:nth-child(2)").text();

Comment: @Aniket Sorry for the unclear explanation. The content is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#left_faq_tips_navi li li').click(function(){
    //here this refers to C/D

    var text = $(this).parent().closest('li')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    console.log(text)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wq8Bh/)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by value? if `html` then try this

```
$('#left_faq_tips_navi li li').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).parents('li').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$('#left_faq_tips_navi li li').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).parents('li')[0]);
});
```